# Having issue resetting JS stopwatch

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

I made a little typing game that reveals some random text and you have to type the same in, so that you can test your typing speed. the users has the ability to play again and again, the issue is that when the user types play again, the stopwatch does not begin as it did the first time.

Can anyone help me with making the stopwatch restart everytime the user clicks on the play again button?

[ full code is here] (https://jsfiddle.net/kisho/ncbxd9o4/#&togetherjs=qD5bT8vLiw)

js portion-

```
const textDisplay = document.querySelector('#text-display');
const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const textBox = document.querySelector('#text-box');
const countdown = document.querySelector('#countdown');
const stopwatch = document.querySelector('#stopwatch');
const successMessege = document.querySelector('#success-messege');
const stopwatchTime = document.querySelector('#stopwatch-time');

btn.addEventListener('click', runGame);

function runGame() {
 if ((btn.innerText = 'Play again')) {
     playAgain();
     fetchQuote();
     countownTimer();
     confirmQuote();
 } else {
     fetchQuote();
     countownTimer();
     confirmQuote();
 }
}

function fetchQuote() {
 fetch('https://api.quotable.io/random')
     .then((res) => {
         return res.json();
     })
     .then((data) => {
         textDisplay.innerText = data.content;
     });
}

function countownTimer() {

if (timer !== undefined) {
     clearInterval(timer);
 }
 var timeleft = 2;
 var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
     if (timeleft <= 0) {
         clearInterval(downloadTimer);
         document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Start Typing!';
         input.classList.remove('displayNone');
         runningStopwatch.classList.remove('displayNone');
         begin();
     } else {
         document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = timeleft + ' seconds remaining';
     }
     timeleft -= 1;
 }, 1000);
}

function confirmQuote() {
 if ((countdown.innerHTML = 'Start typing!')) {
     input.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
         if (event.keyCode === 13) {
             if (textDisplay.innerText === input.value) {
                 btn.innerText = 'Play again';
                 // textBox.classList.add('displayNone');
                 hold();
             } else successMessege.innerText = 'Missed something there, try again!!';
         }
     });
 }
}

function playAgain() {
 textBox.classList.remove('displayNone');
 input.classList.add('displayNone');
 input;
 input.value = '';
 successMessege.innerText = '';
}

let ms = 0,
 s = 0,
 m = 0;
let timer;

let runningStopwatch = document.querySelector('.running-stopwatch');

function begin() {
 timer = setInterval(run, 10);
}

function run() {
 runningStopwatch.textContent =
     (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + ': ' + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s) + ': ' + (ms < 10 ? '0' + ms : ms);
 ms++;
 if (ms == 100) {
     ms = 0;
     s++;
 }
 if (s == 60) {
     s = 0;
     m++;
 }
}

function hold() {
 clearInterval(timer);
 successMessege.innerText = `Nice job! You just typed in x seconds!`;
}

function stop() {
 (ms = 0), (s = 0), (m = 0);
 runningStopwatch.textContent =
     (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + ': ' + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s) + ': ' + (ms < 10 ? '0' + ms : ms);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling the `clearInterval` correctly.

You are clearing the interval *only* if one ends the game successfully.
My solution would be:

When calling the `countownTimer()` function, the first thing you should do, is to check if the interval `timer` is still running.

```
function countownTimer() {
    if (timer !== undefined) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    // [...]
}
```

The next thing would be, to start the interval every time `begin()` gets called.

```
function begin() {
    timer = setInterval(run, 10);
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying mate. with your solution the stopwatch pauses and begins again on the next round. i wanna start it from 0 everytime the user begins typing another answer

Comment: I added to stop() to the playAgain()  to reset the stopwatch and now it works as it should! Thanks so much for your help man!

Comment: Glad I could help